# Short Sitemap question

Tags: html, xml, security, search, browser

If I have a **sitemap_index.xml** file and have it in **root** of my website.

Then I have a **sitemap.xml** file located a couple of directories down, which I **referr to** in the **sitemap_index.xml** file.

Will I be able to have urls inside the **sitemap.xml** file which are on **higher levels** than itself is, for example in the root directory?

Thanks

EDIT:

sitemap_index.xml:

```
 <sitemapindex xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
   <sitemap>
      <loc>http://www.domain.se/directory/sitemap.xml</loc>
      <lastmod>2010-09-28</lastmod>
   </sitemap>
```

sitemap.xml:

```
<url>
      <loc>http://www.domain.se/help.html</loc>
      <lastmod>2010-09-28</lastmod>
      <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
      <priority>0.7</priority>
   </url>
```

sitemap.xml is in a subdirectory, and here it has a  of a directory above itself. Will it still work?

If you need more input let me know.

Comment: How do you refer to that sub-index file? Can you show the exact code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [sitemaps.org](http://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.php), it indeed is not possible to do this:

> The location of a Sitemap file determines the set of URLs that can be included in that Sitemap. A Sitemap file located at http://example.com/catalog/sitemap.xml can include any URLs starting with http://example.com/catalog/ but can not include URLs starting with http://example.com/images/.